# c++, when do you need/have to pass data as (*&)

Tags: c++

I came across people passing data objects as:

declaration:

```
DataObject * data = 0;
```

calling it as:

```
SomeMethod( data );
```

definition of Somethod:

```
void SomeMethod(SomeObject * & object)
```

My obvious question is, when and why do you have to do this (& *)?
Is it passing the pointer as reference?

Comment: Probably a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/

Comment: All good answers, had to choose one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, exactly!

So, not only can your function `SomeMethod` refer to the same `data` as the caller, but it can actually change what the caller points to!

```
int main() {
   SomeObject* data = new SomeObject(1);
   cout << data << " -> " << *data;  // "0xfffee314 -> 1"

   SomeMethod(data);
   cout << data << " -> " << *data;  // "0xeee32435 -> 2"
}

void SomeMethod(SomeObject*& object) {
   delete object;
   object = new SomeObject(2);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Is it passing the pointer as
>   reference?

Yes, that's exactly what it is doing.

This is useful if you want to modify the pointer itself, rather than the data it is pointing to.  Remember that C++ passes by value, so if you pass `SomeObject*`, you are passing a *copy* of the pointer to `SomeObject`.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously if you want to modify the pointer's value (vs the pointee). The alternative would be a pointer to pointer.

For example, SomeMethod might allocate the object and now the caller has the pointer modified to point to that.

```
void foo(Bar*& p)
{
    p = new Bar(...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Personally, I think a pointer to a pointer is the right answer on the rare occasions you actually need to do this - there's something about "*&" that makes my flesh crawl. But perhaps that's just me.

Answer (score 2):

It is passing the pointer as a reference.  This is necessary if you intend to modify the pointer that you are passing to the function.  For example:

```
void change(int *ptr)
{
    ptr = new int;
    *ptr = 5;
}
void change2(int *&ptr)
{
    ptr = new int;
    *ptr = 5;
}

int a = 4;
int *p = &a;
cout << *p << endl;
change(p);
cout << *p << endl;
change2(p);
cout << *p << endl;
```

This will output:

```
4
4
5
```

Edit: in addition to this, change() is leaking memory.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following **C** function:

```
void giveme(char **p) {
    *p = "Hello, World!";
}
```

Which gives you a string. If we were giving the string as a return value, we would have used just a pointer-to-char: `char *giveme()`, but since we use an *out parameter* we must have a pointer to whatever it is we want to return. In this case a pointer to a pointer to char.

One case where you'd meet such code is [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model), where the basic function [`QueryInterface` is defined as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682521%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
HRESULT QueryInterface(
  [in]   REFIID riid,
  [out]  void **ppvObject
);
```

In the following code we want get an `IUnknown` somehow, and want to set the pointer `pWhatever` to point to the `IWhatever` interface of our object. We call `QueryInterface` the following way:

```
IUnknown *pUnk = getIUnknownFromWherever();
IWhatever *pWhatever = NULL;
HRESULT hr;
hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IWHATEVER, &pWhatever);
```

Since we want `QueryInterface` to **change the pointer**, rather than the pointee (the object it point to) we need to give it the address of the pointer.

Now, the whole point of **C++** references is to make life easier in some common scenarios when pointers are used in C. One of them is *out parameters*. So, the previous two code fragments in C++ could have been:

```
// Assume IUnknown::QueryInterface was defined as:
HRESULT QueryInterface(
  [in]   REFIID riid,
  [out]  void *&ppvObject
);

// Now using it could have been somewhat less verbose
// and error prone thanks to references:
IUnknown *pUnk = getIUnknownFromWherever();
IWhatever *pWhatever = NULL;
HRESULT hr;
hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IWHATEVER, pWhatever);
// We're not passing pWhatever, but rather a reference to
// it - but since it's a C++ reference rather than a pointer,
// we don't need to explicitly use the address-of(&) operator
```

And that's it. The point of passing a pointer as reference is basically the same as passing any parameter as non-const reference - have the callee change it. Here we want a pointer (rather than an int or a double) changed so we pass a reference to a pointer.